# How to load my plugin file on joomla's back-end?

Tags: php, joomla

I have developed a joomla extension and want to load a php file within my extension directory onto joomla's back-end (Admin page).

For developing the extension, I have followed the developer document of joomla and install it on an instance of joomla. It located at **administrator\components\com_myextension** as the picture below:

[image: The image of my extension folder under admin directory of joomla]

Note: The root folder of joomla is **jStore**

For my intention, to achieve the result I have to define the behavior in xml file so that **myextension.php** file can be included whenever admin page viewed **or** to write a function to include **myextension.php** file when my extension installed. Neither way I don't know how to do that yet!

In conclusion, what I want to achieve is to load the file **myextension.php** whenever joomla's admin page loaded. And this must be automatically.

Regards,

Dung Tri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a new way to run a php script after my plugin activated.

The way is to develop a **system plugin** for Joomla. The system plugin support some functions that can automatically run when admin page is viewed like: onAfterInitialise, onAfterRoute, onAfterDispatch, onBeforeRender.

You can see a tutorial at [docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a ... for_Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) and download sample project at [github.com/joomla/joomla-cms-examples](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms-examples)